# Односоставное или двусоставное предложение? Постановка запятой

Tags: запятые, союзы, ссп

> Аки Каурисмяки — один из самых авторитетных и значительных
>   представителей европейского авторского кинематографа(,) и поэтому все его
>   фильмы сами по себе вызывают большой интерес.

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом? *Аки Каурисмяки* — это подлежащее? А где в таком случае сказуемое в первой части предложения? Вообще, если первая часть — назывная, то запятую ведь это не отменяет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Аки Каурисмяки — один из самых авторитетных и значительных представителей европейского авторского кинематографа, и поэтому все его фильмы сами по себе вызывают большой интерес.*

Сложносочинённое предложение, состоит из двух двусоставных предложений.

1) Аки Каурисмяки — подлежащее, (есть кто?) один из представителей — составное именное сказуемое;

2) фильмы — подлежащее, (что делают? каковы?) вызывают интерес (интересны) — сказуемое.

Запятая разделяет простые двусоставные  предложения в ССП.

Comment: Чуть подправила Ваш ответ. Снимаю шляпу — добавить нечего.